# TinyMCE and blockquotes

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I have a TinyMCE field initialized as follows:

```
        ... extended_valid_elements: "ul[type],li,a[name|href|target|title],img[class|src|border|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|name|style],hr[class|width|size|noshade],span[class|align|style],iframe[src|class|width|height|name|align],#p/div,strike",
        force_br_newlines: true,
        mode : "none",
        plugins: "autosave",
        relative_urls : false,
        removeformat_selector: "b,strong,i,em,u,s,strike,del,ins,span,font,sup,sub,pre,tt,code,samp,kbd,var,listing,plaintext,xmp,big,small,abbr,acronym,address,bdo,blockquote,cite,q,defn",
        theme : "advanced",
        theme_advanced_blockformats: "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,pre,blockquote",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,fontselect,fontsizeselect,formatselect,forecolor,backcolor,image,link,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,removeformat,fullscreen,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_font_sizes: "x-small=1;small=2;normal=3;large=4;x-large=5;xx-large=6",
        theme_advanced_fonts: "Sans Serif=sans-serif;Serif=serif;Fixed Width=monospace",
        theme_advanced_path: false,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        width: "100%" ...
```

The problem is that blockquotes and alignment are not working.  I can manually insert the corresponding tags into the html of the field, but using the "Indent" button or align buttons does not insert any tags at all, although their preview shows that they are being indented / aligned.

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of TinyMCE are you using? Which tags are you using in the html view to achieve the desired indentation?

TinyMCE adds a "CSS Style" when "Indentation" or "Alignment" buttons are cliked

For eg: Text entered into the edit field gets wrapped inside a 'P' tag like

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

If you click the "Identation" button it will add a style like

```
<p style="padding-left: 30px;">Some text</p>
```

HTH

Comment: How would I verify what tag tinymce uses?  When I click "indent" the text shows up indented in the previewer, but viewing the source of the field shows that it is just wrapped in <p> tags with no extra styling.

Comment: I have experiencing a similar issue. I am using header tags and when I select the align left/center/right buttons the preview appears correctly but the actual HTML hasn't changed at all. Any idea's?

Answer (score 1):

It's the setting: "force_br_newlines: true" that prevents an indentable/alignable <p> tag from being wrapped around your line.

They suggest never using that option and just using some inherited CSS to style all of your paragraphs like <br/>. That doesn't work in my case where I am editing HTML email, but it might work fine for you.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:force_br_newlines